# Sharing model between view and partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a little problem. I have a view (search + search results) that I would break into two parts, I decided to create a partial view with its own controller for the form search and leave the list of results in the view. I need to know if the view and partial view can share the same instance of the model associated with the view and if so, how can I do that?

Comment: Yes. If you use `@Html.Partial("YourPartial")` it will use the main views `ViewDataDictionary` that contains the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you render your partial, you can pass it the model:

```
 @Html.Partial("SearchPartial", Model)
```

And define both your Search view and Search partial view to use the same model type.  For example:

```
 @model SearchModel
```

*Note:* In this case the partial controller will not be called.  This is by design.  If you already have a model and a view, that it doesn't make sense to invoke a controller.  But this mean that your page controller will need to make sure to put everything into the Model that your partial will need.

Comment: but the model passed to the partial view is the same instance of the model in the view? where research ends the model of partial view is "passed" to the view?

Comment: Yes the view engine just passes the instance

Answer (score 0):

Html.Partial has an overload where you can pass the model. To update your result have a look at Ajax.BeginForm... Try to paste some code of what you have so far for more detailed help